# How to define alternative sets of Depends in a deb control file?

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

I'm editing a `control` file of a deb package which contains

```
Depends: nvidia-340 (>=340.29), nvidia-340-uvm (>=340.29), nvidia-340-dev (>=340.29),
nvidia-modprobe (>=340.29), nvidia-settings (>=340.29), libcuda1-340 (>=340.29), 
nvidia-libopencl1-340 (>=340.29), nvidia-opencl-icd-340 (>=340.29)
```

I would like to change the dependency to `nvidia-(...)-343-(...)` for all entries and enforce the choice between all packages being `nvidia-(...)-340-(...)` or all packages being `nvidia-(...)-343-(...)`.

After the lecture of [the debian manual of package relationships](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html) I only know that I could specify `nvidia-340 (>= 340.29)|nvidia-343 (>=343.0), nvidia-340-uvm (>=340.29)|nvidia-343-uvm (>=343.0), ...` which would allow installation of `nvidia-340` together with `nvidia-343-uvm` which is not what I want.

How do I enforce the installation of all packages of one version group only? I'm looking for a generic solution unrelated to the concrete package (NVIDIA cuda toolkit from http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64). The installation should work with `apt-get` after all.

Comment: I am not sure how you define variables, but it is possible to use them in the control file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you aim for, by creating two meta packages (that only contain dependencies) that provide a virtual package (that exists to declare some functionality that some other package can provide). So:

```
Package: nvidia-dependencies-340
Provides: nvidia-dependencies
Depends: nvidia-340 (>=340.29), nvidia-340-uvm (>=340.29), nvidia-340-dev (>=340.29), etc...

Package: nvidia-dependencies-343
Provides: nvidia-dependencies
Depends: nvidia-343 (>=343.0), nvidia-343-uvm (>=343.0), nvidia-343-dev (>=343.0), etc...

Package: my-application
Depends: nvidia-dependencies
```